# Speed up login to StarTeam?

Tags: .net, starteam

I'm working on a program that accesses StarTeam using the StarTeam SDK for .NET. And I've noticed that it takes about 10 seconds to login to the StarTeam server. I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to speed that up.

**Edit**
I used this command to run the StarTeam Cross Platform client with debugging output:
stjava.exe StarTeamCP.stjava -- -netmon
It appears that the delay happens when it send the command SRVR_CMD_GET_USER_PERSONAL_INFO. So I don't think there's anything I can do to speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your starteam server on a remote server (remote location)?  If so could just be cost of going across the wire.  Do you have compression turned on in the connection?  Does it take the same amount of time to connect from an installed client?  If so that would rule out the SDK adding overhead.

Comment: Since it also takes other clients the same about of time, I'm assuming that its something on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Does it take 10 seconds every time for every user or is it just the first time for the first user?

If it's the latter then this sounds like the initial JIT is slowing down start up. If so there are plenty of solutions out there.

Otherwise I'd look at profiling any database queries that go along with logging in.

In other words, try to **break down the time taken to do each part** of the log in process and when you find a **significant chunk of time** try to **reduce or eliminate** it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like its the server getting login information that taking so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the StarTeam client personal options. There's an option under Worksapce | Display called Custom Tools - from the manual  "Displays custom tools created as part of StarTeam Extensions. If no custom tools are configured, clear the Custom tools check box to prevent custom tools from attempting to load with each view window." I've found clearing this field dramatically speeds up the StarTeam client load time, especially over a slower connection. It 'may' help with the SDK app as well, but you will have to test this.